# PHP connecting to MediaWiki API and retrieve data

Tags: php, api, service, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I noticed there was a question somewhat similar to mine, only with c#:[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773029/c-webrequest-to-connect-to-wikipedia-api).
Let me explain: I'm very new to the whole web-services implementation and so I'm experiencing some difficulty understanding (especially due to the vague MediaWiki API manual).

I want to retrieve the *entire page as a string* in PHP (XML file) and then process it in PHP (I'm pretty sure there are other more sophisticated ways to parse XML files but whatever):
[Main Page wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&redirects&titles=Main%20Page).

I tried doing `$fp = fopen($url,'r');`. It outputs: `HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request`. The API does not require a key to connect to it.

Can you describe in detail how to connect to the API and get the page as a string?

**EDIT:**
The URL is `$url='http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&redirects&titles=Main Page';`. I simply want to read the entire content of the file into a string to use it.

Comment: can you show us a little more code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Connecting to that API is as simple as retrieving the file,

[fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

```
$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&redirects&titles=Main%20Page';
$fp = fopen($url, 'r');
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $c .= fread($fp, 8192);
}
echo $c;
```

[file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&redirects&titles=Main%20Page';
$c = file_get_contents($url);
echo $c;
```

The above two can only be used if your server has the `fopen` wrappers enabled.

Otherwise if your server has [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) installed you can use that,

```
$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&redirects&titles=Main%20Page';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$c = curl_exec($ch);
echo $c;
```

Comment: thank you so much! do you know how i can enable fopen wrappers on my local apache?

Comment: make sure allow_url_fopen = 1 in your php ini. http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to urlencode the parameters that you are passing in the query string ; here, at least the "`Main Page`" requires encoding *-- without this encoding, I get a 400 error too*.

If you try this, it should work better *(note the space is replaced by `%20`)* :

```
$url='http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&redirects&titles=Main%20Page';
$str = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump($str);
```

With this, I'm getting the content of the page.

A solution is to use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode), so you don't have to encode yourself :

```
$url='http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&redirects&titles=' . urlencode('Main Page');
$str = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump($str);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the MediaWiki API docs, if you don't specify a User-Agent in your PHP request, WikiMedia will refuse the connection with a 4xx HTTP response code:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page#Identifying_your_client

You might try updating your code to add that request header, or change the default setting in php.ini if you have edit access to that.