# Is there a Wikipedia API just for retrieve the content summary?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I need just to retrieve the first paragraph of a Wikipedia page.

Content must be HTML formatted, ready to be displayed on my website (so *no* [BBCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode), or *Wikipedia* special *code*!)

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't use BB code, it uses its own wiki markup code.

Comment: It doesn't work for every wikipedia article.
https://ro.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&titles=FC+Barcelona&exintro=1&explaintext=1&exsectionformat=plain

Answer (score 248, accepted):

There's a way to get the entire "introduction section" without any HTML parsing!  Similar to [AnthonyS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555320/is-there-a-wikipedia-api-just-for-retrieve-the-content-summary/18504997#18504997) with an additional `explaintext` parameter, you can get the introduction section text in plain text.

### Query

Getting Stack Overflow's introduction in plain text:

Using the page title:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=Stack%20Overflow

Or use `pageids`:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&pageids=21721040

#### JSON Response

(warnings stripped)

```json
{
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "21721040": {
                "pageid": 21721040,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Stack Overflow",
                "extract": "Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network, created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky, as a more open alternative to earlier Q&A sites such as Experts Exchange. The name for the website was chosen by voting in April 2008 by readers of Coding Horror, Atwood's popular programming blog.\nIt features questions and answers on a wide range of topics in computer programming. The website serves as a platform for users to ask and answer questions, and, through membership and active participation, to vote questions and answers up or down and edit questions and answers in a fashion similar to a wiki or Digg. Users of Stack Overflow can earn reputation points and \"badges\"; for example, a person is awarded 10 reputation points for receiving an \"up\" vote on an answer given to a question, and can receive badges for their valued contributions, which represents a kind of gamification of the traditional Q&A site or forum. All user-generated content is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribute-ShareAlike license. Questions are closed in order to allow low quality questions to improve. Jeff Atwood stated in 2010 that duplicate questions are not seen as a problem but rather they constitute an advantage if such additional questions drive extra traffic to the site by multiplying relevant keyword hits in search engines.\nAs of April 2014, Stack Overflow has over 2,700,000 registered users and more than 7,100,000 questions. Based on the type of tags assigned to questions, the top eight most discussed topics on the site are: Java, JavaScript, C#, PHP, Android, jQuery, Python and HTML."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation: [API: query/prop=extracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiHelp/query+extracts)

Comment: It is very recommendable to use **&redirects=1** which redirects automatically to content of synonyms

Comment: How can I get information from this JSON response if I don't know pages number. I can't access JSON array containing "extract"

Comment: @LaurynasG You can cast the object to an array and then grab it like this: $extract = current((array)$json_query->query->pages)->extract

Comment: @LaurynasG, @MarcGuay You can also add `[indexpageids](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Getting_a_list_of_page_IDs) as a parameter to the URL to get a list of pageids for easier iteration.

Comment: I got the json output from the wiki call and then casted the json to array
$data = json_decode($json, true). Then I tries to get the 'extract' using `$extract = current((array)$data->query->pages)->extract;`. but "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" keeps on coming.

Comment: Is there a way to make the same request using the pageid instead of the title?

Comment: @cglacet yup.  Just use the `pageids=` query parameter like so `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&pageids=21721040`

Comment: One more question... on e.g. openstreetmap i get a wikipedia entry e.g. like: `de:Stüdlhütte`. How would I need to put that into the query for it to return me a proper result?

Answer (score 87):

There is actually a very nice **prop** called **[extracts](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TextExtracts#API)** that can be used with queries designed specifically for this purpose.

*Extracts* allow you to get article extracts (truncated article text). There is a parameter called **exintro** that can be used to *retrieve the text in the zeroth section* (no additional assets like images or infoboxes). You can also retrieve extracts with finer granularity such as by a certain number of  characters (**exchars**) or by a certain  number of sentences (**exsentences**).

Here is a **sample query** http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&titles=Stack%20Overflow
and the **API sandbox** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&titles=Stack%20Overflow to experiment more with this query.

Please note that, if you want the first paragraph specifically, you still need to do some additional parsing as suggested in the chosen answer. The difference here is that the response returned by this query is shorter than some of the other API queries suggested, because you don't have additional assets such as images in the API response to parse.

Caveat from the docs:

> We do not recommend the usage of `exsentences`. It does not work for HTML extracts and there are many edge cases for which it doesn't exist. For example "Arm. gen. Ing. John Smith was a soldier." will be treated as 4 sentences. We do not plan to fix this.

Comment: What is "prop"? Property?

Comment: The first link is (effectively) broken. There isn't "extracts" or "extract" on that page.

Comment: Yes, prop is short for property. Updated the link.

Answer (score 87):

Since 2017 Wikipedia provides a [REST API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/REST_API) with better caching. In [the documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/#!/Page_content/get_page_summary_title) you can find the following API which perfectly fits your use case (as it is used by the new [Page Previews](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Page_Previews) feature).

`https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/Stack_Overflow`
returns the following data which can be used to display a summary with a small thumbnail:

```json
{
  "type": "standard",
  "title": "Stack Overflow",
  "displaytitle": "<span class=\"mw-page-title-main\">Stack Overflow</span>",
  "namespace": {
    "id": 0,
    "text": ""
  },
  "wikibase_item": "Q549037",
  "titles": {
    "canonical": "Stack_Overflow",
    "normalized": "Stack Overflow",
    "display": "<span class=\"mw-page-title-main\">Stack Overflow</span>"
  },
  "pageid": 21721040,
  "thumbnail": {
    "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/StackOverflow.com_Top_Questions_Page_Screenshot.png/320px-StackOverflow.com_Top_Questions_Page_Screenshot.png",
    "width": 320,
    "height": 144
  },
  "originalimage": {
    "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a5/StackOverflow.com_Top_Questions_Page_Screenshot.png",
    "width": 1920,
    "height": 865
  },
  "lang": "en",
  "dir": "ltr",
  "revision": "1136271608",
  "tid": "a5580980-9fe9-11ed-8bcd-ff7b011c142c",
  "timestamp": "2023-01-29T15:28:54Z",
  "description": "Website hosting questions and answers on a wide range of topics in computer programming",
  "description_source": "local",
  "content_urls": {
    "desktop": {
      "page": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow",
      "revisions": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow?action=history",
      "edit": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow?action=edit",
      "talk": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Stack_Overflow"
    },
    "mobile": {
      "page": "https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow",
      "revisions": "https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:History/Stack_Overflow",
      "edit": "https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow?action=edit",
      "talk": "https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Stack_Overflow"
    }
  },
  "extract": "Stack Overflow is a question and answer website for professional and enthusiast programmers. It is the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network. It was created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky. It features questions and answers on a wide range of topics in computer programming. It was created to be a more open alternative to earlier question and answer websites such as Experts-Exchange. Stack Overflow was sold to Prosus, a Netherlands-based consumer internet conglomerate, on 2 June 2021 for $1.8 billion.",
  "extract_html": "<p><b>Stack Overflow</b> is a question and answer website for professional and enthusiast programmers. It is the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network. It was created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky. It features questions and answers on a wide range of topics in computer programming. It was created to be a more open alternative to earlier question and answer websites such as Experts-Exchange. Stack Overflow was sold to Prosus, a Netherlands-based consumer internet conglomerate, on 2 June 2021 for $1.8 billion.</p>"
}
```

By default, it follows redirects (so that `/api/rest_v1/page/summary/StackOverflow` also works), but this can be disabled with `?redirect=false`.

If you need to access the API from another domain you can set the [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) header with `&origin=` (e.g., `&origin=*`).

As of 2019: The API seems to return more useful information about the page.

Comment: This also includes "type" which is excellent if you need to know if what you searched has a "disambiguation".

Comment: I am getting CORS error while trying to access this link from my Angular based application can anyone tell me how to resolve that.

Comment: Is it possible to also query by a wikidata ID?
I have some json data I extratcted which looks like

  `"other_tags" : "\"addr:country\"=>\"CW\",\"historic\"=>\"ruins\",\"name:nl\"=>\"Riffort\",\"wikidata\"=>\"Q4563360\",\"wikipedia\"=>\"nl:Riffort\""`
Can we get the extract now by the QID?

Comment: Can this be used to load the summary of more than one page?

Comment: What @SouravChatterjee asked for, can this API be used to search by page ids? Seems not

Answer (score 39):

This code allows you to retrieve the content of the first paragraph of the page in plain text.

Parts of this answer come from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8814262/637987) and thus [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1897606/637987). See [MediaWiki API documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) for more information.

```php
// action=parse: get parsed text
// page=Baseball: from the page Baseball
// format=json: in JSON format
// prop=text: send the text content of the article
// section=0: top content of the page

$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=parse&page=Baseball&prop=text&section=0';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "TestScript"); // required by wikipedia.org server; use YOUR user agent with YOUR contact information. (otherwise your IP might get blocked)
$c = curl_exec($ch);

$json = json_decode($c);

$content = $json->{'parse'}->{'text'}->{'*'}; // Get the main text content of the query (it's parsed HTML)

// Pattern for first match of a paragraph
$pattern = '#<p>(.*)</p>#Us'; // http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10352690
if(preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches))
{
    // print $matches[0]; // Content of the first paragraph (including wrapping <p> tag)
    print strip_tags($matches[1]); // Content of the first paragraph without the HTML tags.
}
```

Comment: But if you search "coral", the result will be something not required. Is there any other way, so that only the p tags with smmary can be picked up

Answer (score 33):

Yes, there is. For example, if you wanted to get the content of the first section of the article [Stack Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow), use a query like this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Stack%20Overflow&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&rvparse

The parts mean this:

- `format=xml`: Return the result formatter as XML. Other options (like JSON) are available. This does not affect the format of the page content itself, only the enclosing data format.
- `action=query&prop=revisions`: Get information about the revisions of the page. Since we don't specify which revision, the latest one is used.
- `titles=Stack%20Overflow`: Get information about the page `Stack Overflow`. It's possible to get the text of more pages in one go, if you separate their names by `|`.
- `rvprop=content`: Return the content (or text) of the revision.
- `rvsection=0`: Return only content from section 0.
- `rvparse`: Return the content parsed as HTML.

Keep in mind that this returns the whole first section including things like hatnotes (“For other uses …”), infoboxes or images.

There are several libraries available for various languages that make working with API easier, it may be better for you if you used one of them.

Comment: I dont want the content parsed ad HTML, i just want to get the "plain text" (neither wikipedia code)

Comment: The API doesn't offer anything like that. And I can understand why: because from the API's perspective, it's not clear what exactly should this "plain text" contain. For example, how should it represent tables, whether to include "[citation needed]", navigational boxes or image descriptions.

Comment: Adding `&redirects=true` to the end of the link ensures you get to the destination article, if one exists.

Answer (score 14):

This is the code I'm using right now for a website I'm making that needs to get the leading paragraphs, summary, and section 0 of off Wikipedia articles, and it's all done within the browser (client-side JavaScript) thanks to the magic of [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)! --> http://jsfiddle.net/gautamadude/HMJJg/1/

It uses the Wikipedia API to get the leading paragraphs (called section 0) in HTML like so: [http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=parse&page=Stack_Overflow&prop=text&section=0&callback=?](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Stack_Overflow&prop=text&section=0&format=json&callback=?)

It then strips the HTML and other undesired data, giving you a clean string of an article summary. If you want you can, with a little tweaking, get a "p" HTML tag around the leading paragraphs, but right now there is just a newline character between them.

Code:

```javascript
var url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow";
var title = url.split("/").slice(4).join("/");

// Get leading paragraphs (section 0)
$.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=parse&page=" + title + "&prop=text&section=0&callback=?", function (data) {
    for (text in data.parse.text) {
        var text = data.parse.text[text].split("<p>");
        var pText = "";

        for (p in text) {
            // Remove HTML comment
            text[p] = text[p].split("<!--");
            if (text[p].length > 1) {
                text[p][0] = text[p][0].split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
                text[p][0] = text[p][0][0];
                text[p][0] += "</p> ";
            }
            text[p] = text[p][0];

            // Construct a string from paragraphs
            if (text[p].indexOf("</p>") == text[p].length - 5) {
                var htmlStrip = text[p].replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '') // Remove HTML
                var splitNewline = htmlStrip.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/); //Split on newlines
                for (newline in splitNewline) {
                    if (splitNewline[newline].substring(0, 11) != "Cite error:") {
                        pText += splitNewline[newline];
                        pText += "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        pText = pText.substring(0, pText.length - 2); // Remove extra newline
        pText = pText.replace(/\[\d+\]/g, ""); // Remove reference tags (e.x. [1], [4], etc)
        document.getElementById('textarea').value = pText
        document.getElementById('div_text').textContent = pText
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you add this to the client-side script?  If so, isn't that XSS?

Comment: It has lot of bugs, try this link with your script : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_Advanced_Armed_Robotic_System

Answer (score 8):

This URL will return summary in XML format.

```
http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryString=Agra&MaxHits=1
```

I have created a function to fetch description of a keyword from Wikipedia.

```php
function getDescription($keyword) {
    $url = 'http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryString=' . urlencode($keyword) . '&MaxHits=1';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    return $xml->Result->Description;
}

echo getDescription('agra');
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also get content such as the first paragraph via [DBPedia](http://dbpedia.org/) which takes Wikipedia content and creates structured information from it ([RDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework)) and makes this available via an API. The DBPedia API is a SPARQL one (RDF-based), but it outputs JSON and it is pretty easy to wrap.

As an example here's a super simple JavaScript library named [WikipediaJS](http://okfnlabs.org/wikipediajs/) that can extract structured content including a summary first paragraph.

You can read more about it in this blog post: *[WikipediaJS - accessing Wikipedia article data through Javascript](http://okfnlabs.org/blog/2012/09/10/wikipediajs-a-javascript-library-for-accessing-wikipedia-article-information.html)*

The JavaScript library code can be found in *[wikipedia.js](https://github.com/okfn/wikipediajs/blob/master/wikipedia.js)*.

Answer (score 2):

The [`abstract.xml.gz` dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download#English-language_Wikipedia) sounds like the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for the text, which you can then split up, but don't want to use the API, take a look at *en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Elephant&action=raw*.

Comment: "ready to be displayed on my websites (so NO BBCODE, or WIKIPEDIA special CODE!)" And this is exactly the oppsite

Answer (score 1):

My approach was as follows (in PHP):

```php
$url = "whatever_you_need"

$html = file_get_contents('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search='.$url);
$utf8html = html_entity_decode(preg_replace("/U\+([0-9A-F]{4})/", "&#x\\1;", $html), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

`$utf8html` might need further cleaning, but that's basically it.

Comment: It is better to ask utf8 from the API with &utf8=

Answer (score 1):

I tried [Michael Rapadas'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555320/is-there-a-wikipedia-api-just-for-retrieve-the-content-summary/28401782#28401782) and @Krinkle's solutions, but in my case I had trouble to find some articles depending of the capitalization. Like here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&exsentences=1&explaintext=&titles=Led%20zeppelin

Note I truncated the response with `exsentences=1`

Apparently "title normalization" was not working correctly:

> Title normalization converts page titles to their canonical form. This
> means capitalizing the first character, replacing underscores with
> spaces, and changing namespace to the localized form defined for that
> wiki. Title normalization is done automatically, regardless of which
> query modules are used. However, any trailing line breaks in page
> titles (\n) will cause odd behavior and they should be stripped out
> first.

I know I could have sorted out the capitalization issue easily, but there was also the inconvenience of having to cast the object to an array.

Because I just really wanted the very first paragraph of a well-known and defined search (no risk to fetch info from another articles), I did it like this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=led%20zeppelin&limit=1&format=json

Note in this case I did the truncation with `limit=1`

This way:

1. I can access the response data very easily.
2. The response is quite small.

But we have to keep being careful with the capitalization of our search.

More information: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Opensearch

Comment: There isn't a user by the name "Krinkle" here. What answer does it refer to? It is one of *"01AutoMonkey"*, *"AnthonyS"*, and *"Alex"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37487650/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler way now with wikimedia enterprise with the `abstract` field. https://enterprise.wikimedia.com/docs/data-dictionary/#abstract in the v2/articles endpoint https://enterprise.wikimedia.com/docs/on-demand/