# Wikipedia API + Cross-origin requests in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a HTTP GET request with [Wikipedia's API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28401782/1837874) with D3.

I'm using http-server to make the request locally. I've used D3 in the past to make HTTP GET requests over an HTTP URL (http://googleapi.com) but am getting an error with this HTTPS.

API request in D3

```
// make API request to wiki
var wiki_api = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=" + node.name;

// get the data
d3.json(wiki_api, function(error, wiki) {
  console.log(wiki);
});
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Blues. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8008' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How can I make HTTPS requests?

Comment: You can't set HTTP response headers on Wikipedia's servers. You don't have access to their server side code.

Comment: Ah, so how can I make an HTTPS request with D3?

Comment: The same way as you make an HTTP request but you put an HTTPS URL in the URL argument. You're already making one, Wikipedia just isn't telling the browser to let your JS read the response.

Comment: It's not D3. You need to load the page that the visualisation is on (i.e. the one on localhost in your case) through HTTPS.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff — That isn't what the error message says.

Comment: @Quentin Oops, you're right -- should've read properly. Ignore that comment :)