# How to get extracts of revisions of wikipedia articles

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I would like to get extracts for old versions (revisions) of wikipedia articles. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555320/is-there-a-clean-wikipedia-api-just-for-retrieve-content-summary) question shows how to get the content in a json format. In particular it uses prop=extracts then explaintext= to return the content. I would like to do the same but for a revision (using revid=*) of an article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using only TextExtracts.  See RFE [T66546 Support revisions](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T66546), which was declined.  In fact, if you try to specify `revids` instead of `titles`, then TextExtracts will return the extract(s) for the current revision(s) of the corresponding title(s).  For example:
[action=query&prop=extracts&exchars=100&explaintext&revids=342428310](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exchars=100&explaintext&revids=342428310)
has equivalent output to:
[action=query&prop=extracts&exchars=100&explaintext&titles=Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exchars=100&explaintext&titles=Earth)

You would need to figure out how TextExtracts prepares an extract and do the same for the revision of interest.