# Display only part of cross-domain webpage

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I am trying to display the infobox vcard (the short bio) from a wikipedia page on my own page. This is obviously on another domain, and I'm struggling to do this. I tried using an iframe first but then I couldn't select only the infobox vcard.

I also tried using the code from [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/), which resulted in the "Woops, there was an error making the request" message (ie I got an onerror event).

The API for WikiMedia seems to only return data, but I want the marked-up version. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: This one could help you. [Is there a clean wikipedia API just for retrieve content summary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555320/is-there-a-clean-wikipedia-api-just-for-retrieve-content-summary)

Comment: This still seems to give me the answer in text and I don't think would work for pictures/links.