# How to get description of an entity/search query from Wikidata API

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, wikidata, wikidata-api

I want to get description of a search query using Wikidata API. I have found that setting parameter `action` to `wbsearchentities` give description of all strings that matches the entity.Can anyone tell me how to get more description about any selected entity like one we have in any search engines on right side of any search engines.

Comment: a) you may get better help at opendata.stackexchange.com b) of course you must provide what you have achieved so far. c) it seems you're mixing up the Mediawiki API and Wikidata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WikiData does not contain "content summary" for entities.

For summary from Wikipedia articles see: [Is there a clean wikipedia API just for retrieve content summary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555320/is-there-a-clean-wikipedia-api-just-for-retrieve-content-summary)  (Be sure to check out the answer regarding [Page Previews](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48527419/57952))