# Response 400 (bad request) when invoking WCF service with other user than Administrator

Tags: wcf, iis-7, proxy, user-permissions, http-status-code-400

I have a simple WCF service (hosted in **Server01**) which I've been using with no problems. After installing in this particular server (lets call it **ClientServer01**), I started to get the response 400.

So we have the following two cenarios.

1. Call WCF service from ClientServer01 from myApp.exe running as *Administrator* - **Works**
2. Call WCF service from ClientServer01 from myApp.exe running as *CustomUser* - **Crashes**

Aditional data:

- ClientServer01 uses a proxy that is inside it's network to communicate
- I'm able to ping Server01 from ClientServer01 using *cmd* running as Administrator and CustomUser both
- Already tried setting `expect100Continue="false"` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033545/wcf-service-access-from-client-application-when-user-is-behind-proxy)
- I've made MyApp.exe to isolate the problem and for debugging purposes, the real application is an IIS website in ClientServer01
- The service is not a big deal. Pretty basic unsecured WCF service with BasicHttpBinding
- **Before asking, I tried to analyse the request with fiddler, it worked, because the component that was really making the request was fiddler. Today I tried it again, but running fiddler as mycustom user** here is the output:

> ERROR
>
> The requested URL could not be retrieved
>
> ---
>
> The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL:
> /MyServiceAppName/MyServiceName.svc
>
> Invalid URL
>
> Some aspect of the requested URL is incorrect.
>
> Some possible problems are:
>
> • Missing or incorrect access protocol (should be “http://” or similar)
>
> • Missing hostname
>
> • Illegal double-escape in the URL-Path
>
> • Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not allowed.
>
> Your cache administrator is webmaster.
>
> ---
>
> Generated Mon, 27 May 2013 13:58:09 GMT by fw3.companyhostname.com.br
> (squid/3.1.11)

Am I missing some server, proxy or WCF configuration that would allow CustomUser to make an http request thought port 80 to a basic WebService?

Thanks

Comment: I recently had a similar problem - not saying that this is the answer, but something to check out. It is possible your client is communicating using IP6, but the service is set up to listen only on IP4. This was my scenario, and I was seeing the 400 response.

Comment: You should turn on activity tracing on both the client and the server and use the trace viewer to see what is going on.  A quick google will show you the WCF config for that and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751795.aspx will show you how to understand the viewer tool.

Comment: I had traced server side before making the question. Client side tracing gave me no helping details, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*CustomUser*'s proxy was not configured. So `UseDefaultWebProxy` would refer to an invalid proxy.

There are some solutions to this kind of problem

1. Set target user proxy settings (the most appropriate IMO)
2. Set binding ProxyAddress property
3. Set default app proxy in .config file tag `configuration/system.net/defaultProxy/proxy` `<proxy proxyaddress="http://ip:port" />`