# "417: Expectation Failed" on HTTPPost

Tags: android, http-post

Very similarly to the Expect Continue problem C# described here, [HTTP POST Returns Error: 417 "Expectation Failed."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566437/http-post-returns-the-error-417-expectation-failed-c-resolved), I was getting an "Expectation Failed" error from the server I was trying to POST to with a HttpPost object in Android.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The equivalent fix to prevent the request from using "expect continue" seems to be this:

```
httpPostInstance.getParams().setParameter(
    CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE,
    Boolean.FALSE);
```

I found this at http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html under 1.6.1.

Comment: Great work buddy. my expectation did not fail :). It continues.