# How do I POST XML generated to a URL?

Tags: c#

I am trying to send XML generated to an URL, I keep getting error with HttpWebResponse:

> The remote server returned an error:(417) Expectation failed

This is my code.

```
 //POST to URL 

            var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000");
            httpRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
            httpRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;


            //Set appropriate headers 

            var xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
            {
                NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None,
                Encoding = Encoding.ASCII
            };

            using (var requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                xmlDoc.Save(requestStream);

            }

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse())
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Response Code to see if the request was successful
                var responseXml = new XmlDocument();
                responseXml.Load(responseStream);
                using (var repp = XmlWriter.Create("response.xml"))
                {
                    responseXml.Save(repp);
                }
            }
```

Comment: The remote server returned an error:(417) Expectation failed

Comment: 417 means that the server could not fulfill the requirements indicated by the client via `Expect` HTTP headers. I am not familiar with `HttpWebRequest` and its default headers but could you inspect the actual HTTP headers being sent, in particular any Expect headers?

Comment: Looks like this? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566437/http-post-returns-the-error-417-expectation-failed-c

Comment: While this has nothing to do with your actual question, I'd like to point out the inconsistency between stating that the content type is `"text/xml; charset=utf-8"`, and then using `Encoding.ASCII`.

Comment: Thanks guys managed to fix it, just had to change the `HttpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion` to `HttpVersion.Version10`