# WebApi returns 417 exception on android HttpUrlConnection(post)

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api

Im trying to send and recieve data from web server with Post method in android .

this is my url call method :

```
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        DataOutputStream printout;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(180000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(180000);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
             connection.setRequestMethod("POST");  
            connection.connect();
                JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                jsonParam.put("IMEI",IMEI);
                PackageManager manager = this.context.getPackageManager();
                PackageInfo info = null;
                try {
                    info = manager.getPackageInfo(
                        this.context.getPackageName(), 0);
                } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String version = info.versionName;
                jsonParam.put("Version",version);
                byte[] data_ = null;
                try {
                    data_ = jsonParam.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data_, Base64.DEFAULT);
                printout = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
                printout.writeBytes(base64);
                printout.flush ();
                printout.close ();
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
            }

            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            String APK_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";

            File dir = new File (APK_PATH);
            dir.mkdirs();
            File _file = new File(dir, "mynew.apk");
            boolean deleted = _file.delete();
            output = new FileOutputStream(_file);
            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                // allow canceling with back button
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    input.close();
                    return null;
                }
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            if (connection != null)
             connection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and it returns 417 exception from server.

im using webapi + squid proxy.
also i put this line in my webconfig :

```
<system.net>
    <settings>
        <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

but it didnt help.

in SO someone fixed the problem with this :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpParams params = httpclient.getParams(); 
params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE,false);
```

but how can i use HttpParams  inside HttpURLConnection  ?!

Answer (score 0):

Just set this static property from `System.Net` to `false` :

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/566847/2424026).

Comment: thanks for respond ,  ive just added <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
to web.config