# 417 Expectation Failed on tableau restapi powershell script

Tags: rest, powershell, tableau-api

I am relatively new at powershell and trying to create REST API calls with powershell version 5.1, to tableau server (version 2018.1), however i am getting an error i am unable to get rid of. The code i am passing is the following:

```
    #Variables:
$sites = 'site'
$APiversion = '3.0'
$DeployPassword = 'Password123'
$DeployUser = 'Defaultuser'
$Tableauservername = 'servername'

# generate body for sign in
$signin_body = (’<tsRequest>
 <credentials name=“’ + $DeployUser + ’” password=“’+ $DeployPassword + ’” >
   <site contentUrl=“” />
 </credentials>
</tsRequest>’)
#[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://$Tableauservername/api/3.0/auth/signin -Body $signin_body -Method post -UseBasicParsing
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
    417 Expectation Failed

Expectation Failed
The expectation given in the Expect request-header
field could not be met by this server.
The client sent
    Expect: 100-continue

Only the 100-continue expectation is supported.


At line:16 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://$Tableauservername/api/3.0 ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Doe s anyone know what i am doing wrong here?

I already changed formatting of quotes etc. does not seem to work.

Comment: Try setting the Expect header with the `-Headers` parameter.

Comment: I have tried, but have no idea what to put there, also, should it be put in the body or in the rest-method?

Comment: Have you tried `-Header @{}` or `-Header @{Expect=""}` maybe?

Comment: I have restarted the powershell console which seemed to (temporarily) clean up te the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP POST Returns Error: 417 "Expectation Failed."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566437/http-post-returns-error-417-expectation-failed)

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49056005/2060966)